# Apache Install can't browse to localhost

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2, webserver, lamp

First time setting up Apache, using Ubuntu server 12.04.02

I am using this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

Seems pretty straight forward, except I can't navigate to the webserver with my browser. I tried IE and Chrome. Chrome gives me the "Oops, this website can't be found" message.

Comment: Are you running the server with `sudo service apache2 restart`? If so and that doesn't work, try  `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure why that link is broken, works fine for me. I did try restarting the apache server using both of the methods you mentioned Jeremy, still no luck.

Comment: @Alkthree Hmm... try  removing apache2 `sudo apt-get remove apache2`, do the same with all other related plug ins you installed. Once it's all removed, **just** do `sudo apt-get install apache2`. Then start the server with the methods listed above. Also: what happens when you type the commands? Anything? If what I suggested didn't work, try `sudo -s` then run the commands (without `sudo`). Also, make sure to ping me (@Jeremy) when trying to tell me something so I get a notification.

Comment: @Jeremy I got it working, I forgot to set the guest VM to bridged networking. My bad guys!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure if you install Apache within a VM that it is set up with Bridged networking